# How to i add deeplink to instagram Ads?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have created a facebook ad by using [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads) deeplinking is working fine if app is already installed then on click of install button in facebook it directly opens the app but for the same facebook ad i have posted in instagram it is always taking us to playstore.

Ads i have debugged the issue on click of install button in instagram ad

```
Intent Action : 
android.intent.action.VIEW 
is broadcasted with market: uri.
```

So it is taking me to playstore.

Is there any instagram specific settings i need to be done on facebook ads manager so that deeplink will work on instagram app.